# Wordpress has detected that your site is running on a insecure version of php

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I have just finished setting up WordPress installation and my WordPress theme on my Cpanel, but after everything was set up and I logged in to wp-admin I receive a warning that "Wordpress has detected that your site is running on an insecure version of PHP" but it did not give a possible fix to the problem, I am pretty sure am using the latest version of PHP but could anything else cause that?

Comment: Check the server and actually see what version you are running. We can't make guess, related topic https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-has-detected-that-your-site-is-running-on-an-insecure-version-of-php/

Comment: @user3783243  i just checked its 5.6.40 , any suggestions on how i can fix this as am using a hosting provider

Comment: Are you running other PHP applications on the server? You could ask your host to upgrade you.

Comment: @user3783243 i have just asked my provider to update me hopefully that will fix  the issue thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking the PHP version first. Starting with WordPress 5.2 there is a tool named "Health Check" (in the administration under `Tools`) where you can check the PHP version (click the `Info` tab and expand the `Server` section).

If the PHP version is lower than 7.1 I would definitely recommend upgrading (in the hosting control panel or by contacting your hosting provider directly). Using an outdated PHP version can be a security risk for your websites (see [this link](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) for supported PHP versions).

Just ensure to test your website thoroughly after upgrading PHP as some plugins or the theme might not support the new version and trough some errors, or even prevent you from logging in to your website.